# Python POST request - set whole raw post body?

Tags: python, post, request

I want to send a POST request with Python, setting the whole POST body to be a certain string lets say. How would I do that? urlib/urlib2/httplib, doesn't matter to me...

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example urllib2 seems to allow for setting the body (and also headers) in a straightforward way: http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.Request